# Remote SSH disabled after each reboot - Sharing

Tags: 20.04, ssh, remote-access, sharing, sshd

I have a desktop installation of Ubuntu 20.04 with X11. I have installed SSHD, and enabled Remote Login in the Sharing page of Settings in the Desktop.

[image: Picture of setting]

Then it works to SSH into the machine from a remote computer.

But the problem is that after each reboot the "Remote Login" setting is turned off. This happens every time I reboot. So I have to log in locally to again to the desktop and enable Remote Login, after that it works until next reboot.

Any tips on how to solve this would be great